# Windows Batch File: for /F read only first line of mylist.txt and delete first line afterwards

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, command

I run a  batch script:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%F IN (mylist.txt) do C:\VideoConverter\Applications\ffmpeg.exe ^
-f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 0.1 -i "%%~F" -i "%~dpn1.mp3" -codec:v libx264 ^
-s 1920x1080 -acodec copy -strict experimental -movflags faststart -t 00:10:10.00 ^
-f mp4 "%~dpn1.mp4"
```

In my folder are the following files:

```
file001.mp3
file002.mp3
file003.mp3
```

mylist.txt contains:

```
pic001.jpg 
pic002.jpg 
pic003.jpg
```

At the moment the script creates 3 videos with 3 different background images for every mp3 in the folder. This is wrong.

I want to create only these three videos.

```
video 1 = file001.mp3 + pic001.jpg (line1) 
video 2 = file002.mp3 + pic002.jpg (line2)
video 3 = file003.mp3 + pic003.jpg (line3)
```

Can someone help me with the for `/f` command? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please format multi-line code and data the same way as you formatted the last code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would loop through the videos using `for`, push mylist.txt into the `for` loop via stdin (with a `<`), and let `set /p` capture it line-by-line (once per loop iteration).  Something like this:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

(
    for %%I in (*.mp3) do (

        rem // set /P grabs one line of input from stdin
        set /P "imagefile="

        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if defined imagefile call :build "%%~I" "!imagefile!" "%%~dpnI.mp4"
        endlocal

        set "imagefile="
    )
) < mylist.txt
rem // The line above dumps mylist.txt into stdin, letting set /P grab one line at a time.

goto :EOF

:build <in_mp3> <in_image> <outfile>
C:\VideoConverter\Applications\ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 0.1 ^
-i "%~1" -i "%~2" -codec:v libx264 -s 1920x1080 -acodec copy -strict experimental ^
-movflags faststart -t 00:10:10.00 -f mp4 "%~3"
```

Comment: What about `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:N *.mp3`) do` to guarantee the correct sort order, given that `mylist.txt` is sorted either?

Comment: I changed `-i "%~1" -i "%~2" with -i "%~2" -i "%~1"` and it worked. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @aschipfl i have to do some tests to see if a further modification of the code would be necessary.